# Style conflicts caused by using v-if and custom directives at the same time

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

#### Version

2.5.2

#### Reproduction link

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-roentgen-rp1x3)

#### Steps to reproduce

1. click the white button
2. v-wide will change the backgroundColor

#### What is expected?

The second popup's backgroundColor should be blue

#### What is actually happening?

The popup's backgroundColor is red that is the previous one

---

I use v-if and a custom directives to update the inline style at the same time. when the next element is displayed, it will inherit the style of the previous one.And the displayed element doesn't trigger the inserted lifecycle.

some code:

v-wide

```
const wide = Vue.directive("wide", {
  inserted: function (e, binding, vnode) {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(e);
    console.log(style.backgroundColor);
    if (style.backgroundColor == "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
      e.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  }
});
```

app.vue

```
<div class="popup popup1" v-if="showPopup1" v-wide>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <div class="btn" @click="showPopup1 = false;showPopup2 = true;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="popup popup2" v-if="showPopup2" v-wide>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <div class="btn" @click="showPopup2 = false"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, provide all relevant code in the question. It's good there's a link but the question won't make sense when it becomes unavailable.

Comment: Try use different `key` between 2 popups.

Comment: @EstusFlask I have added relevant code

Comment: @User28 u are right. thank you!